# Automated way to create EXT4 Partition on Windows 10

Tags: windows, partitioning, filesystems, sd-card, ext4

### The Problem

Partitioning 32GB uSD cards with 2GB FAT32/~30GB EXT4 in a production environment (20 per day) performed by production technicians (people who need something that's simple as a single click)

### The Status

I know there are GUIs out there. I don't want a GUI.

I know it can be done from Linux. I don't want to run a Linux machine in our production floor.

I know I can create an master ISO and use it to image disks. This takes forever.

### Acceptable solutions:

I'm looking to create an EXT4 partition from Windows in an automated way. I know this is possible because all these little GUIs are able to do it when I click a the right buttons.

- PowerShell script (probably not possible)
- 3rd Party tool that can be launched in an automatic mode with arguments (AOMEI partition assistant doesn't support EXT4 from arguments)
- 3rd Party library I can use to write a tool myself.
- Some kind of document that explains how to partition a disk even if it means setting raw 1s and 0s on the disk so I could write the damn thing myself and stop making endless searches

Any help is *greatly* appreciated

Comment: If anyone knows of a better forum that I should post this on, I'm happy to try there as well

Comment: I haven't tried.. (thus the comment) but Windows 11 WSL2 is supposed to be able to access EXT4 in all of its glory.  This might be no different to you than running a Linux machine on the floor though.  [Ext4Fsd](https://github.com/bobranten/Ext4Fsd) is supposed to be able to do this.. but I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: OK, I'll look into EXT4FSD. For WSL2, is it possible to start this automatically? So if I could launch WSL2 from powershell and have it run a bash script, that'd work fine.

Comment: @stevep The only way I know of to create ext4 partitions on Windows is via Paragon's [Linux Filesystems for Windows](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/linuxfs-windows/) and it does [support](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/linuxfs-windows/#faq) CLI _(second from the bottom under Features)_

Comment: You say writing an image "takes forever" – why do you think writing data from an image takes longer than writing the exact same data using a filesystem creation tool?

Comment: Well, I can create two empty partitions like I want with AOEMI almost instantly (<5s of waiting time), where writing an ISO takes significantly longer. Besides, I'd prefer to manage a script that I can change instead of shuffling around a "master file"

Comment: @JW0914 Thank you. Through The LinuxFileSystems, I found that mke2fs creates an EXT4 partition thought command line, and it's open source

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [JW0914](https://superuser.com/users/529800/jw0914) for the help. The open source [Ext2 File System Driver for Windows](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2fsd/files/Mke2fs/)  can be used to format an partition as EXT4 in Win10. Install and add it to PATH so it can be used from command prompt/PowerShell

### Example for an SD card set to disk number 4

Create and format the first partition with PowerShell

```
New-Partition -DiskNumber 4 -Size 2GB  -AssignDriveLetter | Format-Volume -FileSystem FAT32 -NewFileSystemLabel MyDrive
```

Create a second unformatted partition with PowerShell

```
New-Partition -DiskNumber 4 -UseMaximumSize
```

Use mke2fs to format the second partition.

```
mke2fs -t ext4 -L "Ext4Volume" /dev/sde2
```